# What needs to dominate an input: call to action or the current value?

Tags: usability, buttons, input

#### Context:

- Cinema ticket booking app.
- App displays movie screenings in a geographical location.
- Initial location is determined using user IP.
- User can change their location by entering an address.

#### Task:

- Inform user of the location used to display screenings.
- Enable user to change the location (clicking this button will make it into a text field with the current address).

#### Visual example:

Dominating present value.

[image: Dominating value.]

Dominating call to action.

[image: Dominating call to action.]

Neither dominate. Call to action is made to look different from the content.

[image: Dominating value v2.]

#### Question:

What needs to dominate, the current value or the call to action?

Answer (score 1):

**Present value** can be dominating in this case.

Reason:

1. User will know his current location and will if the need be will click on it to change it, if the location is not accurate. (This is basic psychology, where a person will try to interact with the element which he believes is incorrect.)
2. Putting Call to Action into domination shows that you aren't confident enough if you have detected the location accurately. Also, focusing the User on the Call to Action, rather than the Location itself.

Putting Present Value in domination focuses the location to the user, through which, if it's incorrect, he can read the Call to Action below and interact with it.

P.S. Why aren't you asking permission to access the location?

Comment: "P.S. Why aren't you asking permission to access the location?"

We did a simple A/B test. Absolute majority of users whose location we detected using IP and whose intent was to book in their area, are happy with the approximate results and do not change address (they might adjust location using map, which is part of the interface).

Comment: It is only the users that want to book in a different city that will be interested to change the location.

Comment: As I typed this out, it made me think whether showing user the current location is a good idea to begin with. The detected address that we display  is mostly meaningless to the user anyway.

Comment: Going to display only city and country name when address is detected automatically.

Comment: Now that you've edited the Question, the Third approach is perfect. I was going to suggest that, however I thought you only had these two options to choose from.

Comment: Yes, City and Country Name sounds good. BookMyShow.com does the same.